# How to add zero/zeroes at the beginning of an integer value in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, integer, prefix, octal

I've a variable titled `$value` as follows :

```
$value = 5985;
```

If I `echo 05985;` it prints 15. I understood that PHP considers this number as octal and prints 15 but I don't want 15 I want leading zero/zeroes prefixed to a value contained in a variable `$value`.

But I want to make it five or say six digits long. In that case I need to add leading zero/zeroes to the value contained in a variable `$value`. When I add those leading zeroes and echo the variable `$value` it should look like as follows :

```
05985; //If I want five digit number
005985; //If I want six digit number
```

I searched and tried following approach but it didn't work out.

```
str_pad($value, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
sprintf('%08d', $value);
echo $value;
```

So can someone please suggest me how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: An int is a number. A number doesn't have any digits, so you can't add a leading zero anywhere. The important difference is the one between a number and the representation of a number, you want a particular representation. For that, there are formatting functions that can pad numbers with zeroes or spaces. You can't write such a number in code though, because PHP requires a certain format for the representations there, as you noticed yourself. That said, `str_pad()` works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sprintf does not directly change the value of its second parameter, it returns the result. Try

```
$value = sprintf('%08d', $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to treat it as a string.

```
$number = '05433';

Echo $number;
```

Should give you what you want. You can also add a zero like this

```
$number = '0' . $number;
```